# Merging two Arrays on Unique ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am looking for some advice on how to improve this method as I don't like the work around.

I have two Object Arrays with Json.

The first has all the dates in a date range, the second list comes from a SQL query, where some months may be missing.

The desired out come needs to be a list with all the months in order with a matterCount, however when I load them into the function below I am missing the matterCount on months that did not exist on the list.

I think that I am just missing a little bit of code out the function, but I am not entirely sure what, hence coming here.

I do have a work around which is in the JSFiddle but I would prefer clearer code.

```
let x = [{labelDate: "Jun 2013"},
{labelDate: "Jul 2013"},
{labelDate: "Aug 2013"},
{labelDate: "Sep 2013"},
{labelDate: "Oct 2013"},
{labelDate: "Nov 2013"},
{labelDate: "Dec 2013"},
{labelDate: "Jan 2014"},
{labelDate: "Feb 2014"},
{labelDate: "Mar 2014"},
{labelDate: "Apr 2014"},
{labelDate: "May 2014"}];


let y = [{labelDate: "Jun 2013", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Jul 2013", matterCount: "2"},
{labelDate: "Aug 2013", matterCount: "2"},
{labelDate: "Sep 2013", matterCount: "10"},
{labelDate: "Oct 2013", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Nov 2013", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Feb 2014", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Apr 2014", matterCount: "17"},
{labelDate: "May 2014", matterCount: "21"}];

const merge = (x, y) =>
            x.map(xItem => ({
              ...y.find(yItem => yItem.labelDate === xItem.labelDate && Item),
              ...xItem
            }));

Actual outcome 
merge = [{labelDate: "Jun 2013", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Jul 2013", matterCount: "2"},
{labelDate: "Aug 2013", matterCount: "2"},
{labelDate: "Sep 2013", matterCount: "10"},
{labelDate: "Oct 2013", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Nov 2013", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Dec 2013"},
{labelDate: "Jan 2014"},
{labelDate: "Feb 2014", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Mar 2014"},
{labelDate: "Apr 2014", matterCount: "17"},
{labelDate: "May 2014", matterCount: "21"}];

desired outcome 
merge  = [{labelDate: "Jun 2013", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Jul 2013", matterCount: "2"},
{labelDate: "Aug 2013", matterCount: "2"},
{labelDate: "Sep 2013", matterCount: "10"},
{labelDate: "Oct 2013", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Nov 2013", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Dec 2013", matterCount: "0"},
{labelDate: "Jan 2014", matterCount: "0"},
{labelDate: "Feb 2014", matterCount: "1"},
{labelDate: "Mar 2014", matterCount: "0"},
{labelDate: "Apr 2014", matterCount: "17"},
{labelDate: "May 2014", matterCount: "21"}];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cp39aoyf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `||`'ing a default value:

```
const merge = (x, y) =>
        x.map(xItem => ({
          ...y.find(yItem => yItem.labelDate === xItem.labelDate && yItem) || {...xItem, matterCount: "0"}
        }));
```

[Demo JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/j0ba6dzo/3/)

Another way would be to simply add the default value which would be overriden by the `yItem`, if it exists:

```
const merge = (x, y) =>
    x.map(xItem => ({
      ...xItem,
      ...{matterCount: "0"},
      ...y.find(yItem => yItem.labelDate === xItem.labelDate && yItem)
    }));
```

[Fiddle for this one.](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/5yac0s89/)

Comment: I like this solution more then my work around, 

The only thing is that I was trying to make my merge function generic to use on other arrays with different values. So hard coding matterCount in there would negate that.

Comment: Yes, but do notice that `"0"` is a hardcoded (or magic) value. It would have to be provided in some way. I mean, if your function is generic, how will it know it should be `"0"`?

Comment: I see the point you are trying to make,

I guess in this situation though, I know its Zero because if nothing was returned from the SQL query it is Zero.

Comment: If you think `"0"` is a valid value for every absent property, how about this: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/L7u928kz/

Comment: We both are on the same thought path, 

Here is mine 

 const merge = (x, y, key, column) =>
            x.map(xItem => ({
              ...xItem,
              ...{ [column]: "0" },
              ...y.find(yItem => yItem[key] === xItem[key] && yItem)
            }));



Thanks bud